# ConcurrentSkipListMap cannot have key which is not Comparable, right?

Tags: java, collections

This part in API docs is same for both TreeMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap.

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by
>   a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

Ideologically, ConcurrentSkipListMap (being a NavigableMap) shall be sorted (and thus maintain order internally) just like TreeMap. Without being Comparable (if we specify no special Comparator in the constructor) ConcurrentSkipListMap cannot consistlently maintain any order.

But unlike TreeMap, ConcurrentSkipListMap throws no exception if given a non-comparable key! This puzzles me, why:

```
        TreeMap<ArrayList, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
        m.put(new ArrayList(), 6); // throws ClassCastException - ArrayList not Comparable

        ConcurrentSkipListMap<ArrayList, Integer> lst = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        lst.put(new ArrayList(), 6); // fine!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't throw an exception on the *first* key.  It'll throw an exception if you add a second key.  This is just because `ConcurrentSkipListMap` doesn't have special logic to verify that the first key is comparable, but that was added for `TreeMap`.  I suspect this is just a JDK oversight.